# How to provide alternate image if url is null in flutter?

Tags: image, firebase, flutter

I am using below code to represent a image retrieved from a url in Firebase.
If in case url is `null` how should I set an alternate image from `assets` in flutter application?

```
CircleAvatar( radius: 50,
              backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(picUrl),
                  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

```
CircleAvatar( radius: 50,
              backgroundImage: picUrl != null ? CachedNetworkImageProvider(picUrl) : AssetImage(lib/assets/yourImage.png),
)
```